According to panpsychism, is ChatGPT conscious or sentient?
SEP defines panpsychism as follows:

Panpsychism is the view that mentality is fundamental and ubiquitous in the natural world. The view has a long and venerable history in philosophical traditions of both East and West, and has recently enjoyed a revival in analytic philosophy. For its proponents panpsychism offers an attractive middle way between physicalism on the one hand and dualism on the other. The worry with dualism—the view that mind and matter are fundamentally different kinds of thing—is that it leaves us with a radically disunified picture of nature, and the deep difficulty of understanding how mind and brain interact. And whilst physicalism offers a simple and unified vision of the world, this is arguably at the cost of being unable to give a satisfactory account of the emergence of human and animal consciousness. Panpsychism, strange as it may sound on first hearing, promises a satisfying account of the human mind within a unified conception of nature.
[...]
2. Varieties of Contemporary Panpsychism
2.1 The Definition of Panpsychism
The word “panpsychism” literally means that everything has a mind. However, in contemporary debates it is generally understood as the view that mentality is fundamental and ubiquitous in the natural world. Thus, in conjunction with the widely held assumption (which will be reconsidered below) that fundamental things exist only at the micro-level, panpsychism entails that at least some kinds of micro-level entities have mentality, and that instances of those kinds are found in all things throughout the material universe. So whilst the panpsychist holds that mentality is distributed throughout the natural world—in the sense that all material objects have parts with mental properties—she needn’t hold that literally everything has a mind, e.g., she needn’t hold that a rock has mental properties (just that the rock’s fundamental parts do).
We can distinguish various forms of panpsychism in terms of which aspect of mentality is taken to be fundamental and ubiquitous. Two important characteristics of human minds are thought and consciousness. In terms of these characteristics we can distinguish the following two possible forms of panpsychism:

Panexperientialism—the view that conscious experience is fundamental and ubiquitous
Pancognitivism—the view that thought is fundamental and ubiquitous.

According to the definition of consciousness that is dominant in contemporary analytic philosophy, something is conscious just in case there is something that it’s like to be it; that is to say, if it has some kind of experience, no matter how basic.[7] Humans have incredibly rich and complex experience, horses less so, mice less so again. Standardly the panexperientialist holds that this diminishing of the complexity of experience continues down through plants, and through to the basic constituents of reality, perhaps electrons and quarks. If the notion of “having experience” is flexible enough, then the view that an electron has experience—of some extremely basic kind—would seem to be coherent (of course we must distinguish the question of whether it is coherent from the question of whether it is plausible; the latter will depend on the strength of the arguments discussed below).

According to panpsychism, does ChatGPT have a mind? In other words, is ChatGPT conscious or sentient?
If so, what is it like to be ChatGPT?

Why do think there is a relation at all between panpsychism, ChatGPT, being conscious and being sentient? Thanks.

Subtly conservative panpsychism with a psychic sky view even for an electron doesn't mean high level consciousness...

Panpsychism is largely irrelevant to the question of what if any consciousness(es) a computer running ChatGPT has that are special to computers running ChatGPT.
First, we can grant panpsychism and deny that gestalt objects like computers, rocks, and your individual toes are the sorts of objects that have mind, as opposed to the atoms or quantum fields that compose or generate them.
Second, if we grant panpsychism and grant that such gestalt objects have mind, then ChatGPT is just one of countless gestalt objects with mind. And in terms of the operations required to do what it actually does, not what humans find useful about it, those computers do roughly the same operations as a similarly sized electric heater: sit around being hot matter in a cool room. No small matter, if you're a panpsychist!
If we grant panpsychism, grant that gestalt objects have mind, and further grant that gestalt objects have many, possibly infinitely many, minds with different characteristics, and then try to investigate what characteristics the one mind associated with ChatGPT's specially useful-to-humans processes might have... then we're in the same place we would be as if we denied panpsychism, denied that gestalt objects (generally) have mind or minds, guessed that ChatGPT's special processes had mind, and then tried to investigate what characteristics it had, if it did have mind.
So panpsychism is irrelevant to the question, since we can ask the same exact question with or without it.

It's not clear that there is a "mind" that correlates uniquely to ChatGPT, if only because its implemented on a highly distributed system so it's not clear there is the necessary physical connectedness to support (ontologically) a mind.
ChatGPT gives a great emulation of a mind at work, but Panpsychism is not functionalism -- there is something about how things are put together that creates a particular experience of a mind from the generic "mind" that is present as a capacity in all things, not just how they behave (i.e., Searle's Chinese Room's does not understand Chinese -- or anything as its not constituting a mind).

+1. Note also, as an addendum, that ChatGPT is effectively a very fast implementation of Searle's Chinese Room. It does not "understand" what is being given to it, only taking an input vector and turning it into an output vector (which, with the magic of natural language tokenization, corresponds on both ends to human-language strings).

@controlgroup - thanks! good addendum! I work in AI/NLP and GenAI engineering - ChatGPT is indeed a technical marvel, but it is "vectors in, vectors out" with maybe some stochasticity thrown in there


According to panpsychism consciousness is ubiquitous. "Ubiquitous" means "being everywhere". Thus, panpsychism holds that conscious is everywhere; in other words, that everything is conscious or somehow partakes in consciousness.
ChatGPT is something.
Therefore, ChatGPT, according to panpsychism, is conscious.

Panpsychism may or may not hold the opinion that x being consious requires that there should be "something that it is like to be x". But even apart from various, speculative theories of panpsychism, in the wiki article you linked to you can see that several other philosophers have raised serious doubts about the validity of that extremely vague 'characteristic' of consciousness. Notably

Peter Hacker analyzes Nagel's statement as not only "malconstructed"
but philosophically "misconceived" as a definition of
consciousness, and he asserts that Nagel's paper "laid the
groundwork for…forty years of fresh confusion about
consciousness."

If you want to know Hacker's (or other's) arguments - please follow the links  mentioned in Wikipedia.
